# TSQL Copy Dilemma with Uniqueidentifier

Tags: sql, t-sql, copy, uniqueidentifier

I am trying to create test data for a table with an uniqueidentifier as well as a sub-table with a foreign key that references that uniqueidentifier.

How would I go about copying every row in each table, while keeping the same relationship between each references table. I am having trouble figuring out how I would reference the newly created uniqueidentifier from the sub-table with the foreign key.

Thanks!

**MAIN_TABLE**

```
MAIN_ID
1234
5678
```

**SUB_TABLE**

```
SUB_ID    MAIN_ID
abcd      1234
efgh      5678
```

now copying the data in each entry for MAIN_TABLE

**MAIN_TABLE**

```
MAIN_ID
1234
5678
9123
4567
```

**SUB_TABLE**

```
SUB_ID    MAIN_ID
abcd      1234
efgh      5678
ijkl      9123
mnop      4567
```

How would I know how to reference the newly create uniqueidentifier for use in the sub table as a foreign key.

Comment: Post your table structures.  I can't picture what's so difficult about your requirement.

Comment: @TabAlleman updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inserting new values using helper variable to hold generated `NEWID`:

```
CREATE TABLE #main(main_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE #sub(sub_id VARCHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY,
                  main_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES #main(main_id)
                  );

DECLARE @new_guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID();

INSERT INTO #main(main_id)
VALUES (@new_guid);

INSERT INTO #sub(sub_id, main_id)
VALUES ('abc', @new_guid);


SELECT *
FROM #main

SELECT *
FROM #sub;
```

Copying data from one table to another:

```
INSERT INTO #main_new(main_id);
SELECT main_id
FROM #main;

INSERT INTO #sub_new(sub_id, main_id)
SELECT sub_id, main_id
FROM #sub;
```

**EDIT:**

Example of reinserting data using join and temporary table and then insert specific columns to tables.

```
SELECT NEWID() as guid, sub_id, [rn] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY m.main_id)
INTO #temporary
FROM #main m
JOIN #sub s
  ON m.main_id = s.main_id


INSERT INTO #main
SELECT guid
FROM #temporary;

INSERT INTO #sub
SELECT CONCAT(sub_id, rn), guid
FROM #temporary;

SELECT *
FROM #main;

SELECT *
FROM #sub;
```

Comment: I understand using the helper variable, but how could i use that same idea across an entire table with 10s or 100s of entries? once the first copy is made it would try to insert the store uniqueidentifier @new_guid and fail because it would not be unique. thanks for the help!

Comment: @wellmannered `INSERT INTO main VALUES ('guid_1'), ('guid_2'), (guid_3)` and `INSERT INTO sub VALUES ('abc', 'guid_1'), ('efg', 'guid_2'), ('hij', 'guid_3')`;

Comment: so there is no way with this method to automate this, the table i am working with has 100s of entries?

Comment: @wellmannered I already posted in my answer this scenario. Use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` first for main and then sub table

Comment: I also did see that, but I would need those entries to be copied to the same tables that I copied them from. Sorry for the confusion. Essentially I need to copy all data from MAIN and SUB to MAIN and SUB, the only difference with the new values would be their newly created uniqueidentifier. With your method, to my understanding, I would have to manually enter a new guid for each entry explicitly.

Comment: @wellmannered And how sub_id should be generated for new entries? It is identity column?

Comment: @wellmannered Never mind check this [demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/377609). It is possible, just do normal join to one table then reinsert selecting columns for each table. Piece of cake.

Comment: Thank you. this makes more sense. +100